# JQuery Expand and collapse Tree List

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm new on jquery. I have a list with sub list. I want to apply expand/collapse function to all of them.

html:

```
<ul class="tree-child">
    <li class="link">
        <span><a href="#">folderrename</a></span>
        <ul>
            <li class="link">
                <span><a href="#">TR</a></span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="link">
                        <span><a href="#">Test</a></span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li> 
            <li class="link">
                <span><a href="#">movefolder</a></span>
            </li>
            <li class="link">
                <span class=""><a href="#">Rel 7.60_SOLASE</a></span>
            </li>
            <li class="link">
                <span><a href="#">TestStdFolder1</a></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to expand/collapse on `<span><a href="#">folderrename</a></span>` on click with + and - icon. For icon I use font awesome.

**[Reference Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umutc1/eyf9q87c/).**

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `slideToggle()` :

```
$('#folder_rename').on('click',function(){
  $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('span').on('click',function(){
  $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus');
})
```

```css
span{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="tree-child">
  <li class="link">
    <span id='folder_rename'>
      <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
      <a href="#">folderrename</a></span>
    <ul>
      <li class="link">
        <span><i class="fa fa-minus"></i><a href="#">TR</a></span>
        <ul>
          <li class="link">
            <span><a href="#">Test</a></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li> 
      <li class="link">
        <span><a href="#">movefolder</a></span>
      </li>
      <li class="link">
        <span class=""><a href="#">Rel 7.60_SOLASE</a></span>
      </li>
      <li class="link">
        <span><a href="#">TestStdFolder1</a></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: working only first '<span id='folder_rename'><a href="#">folderrename</a></span>'. I want to all of down tree as first.

Comment: Thanks @ Zakaria ...and if I want one level more?